# CGPoint compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, core-graphics

I've tried to write an expression:

```
 var  moveDifference: CGPoint = CGPoint(touchPoint.x - self.anchorPointInPoints().x, touchPoint.y - self.anchorPointInPoints().y)
```

But xcode swears:

> Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Please help to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the *argument labels* on the `CGPoint` initializer:

```
CGPoint(x: ..., y: ...)
```

Also: thanks to *type inference*, you really don't need to redeclare your var type:

```
var moveDifference = CGPoint(...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paulo

Comment: @OlegSavelyev Glad to help :-)